# Show text Below Progress indicator in android

Tags: android

I am showing a progress bar while switching from one screen to another.
It is the circular progress bar and there is a message in it "Loading"
This message is appearing on the right side of progress bar.
I want to show it below the circular loading. Is it possible?

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(test2.this, "", "Initializing", false); 
Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable(){ 
    public void run(){ 
        startActivity(new Intent(test2.this, test.class)); 
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){ 
            public void run() { 
                if(progressDialog.isShowing()) 
                    progressDialog.dismiss(); 
        }}); 
}}); 
thread.start();
```

Comment: progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(test2.this, "", "Initializing", false);
     Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable(){
              public void run(){
               startActivity(new Intent(test2.this, test.class));
                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                      public void run() {
                          if(progressDialog.isShowing())
                           progressDialog.dismiss();  
                      }
                  });
              }
         });
         thread.start();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you have to create a custom dialog box something like below modify it to suit your needs

```
public static void showProgressDialog(Context mContext, String text, boolean remove)
{
    mDialog = new Dialog(mContext, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View layout = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_example, null);
    mDialog.setContentView(layout);

    TextView mTextView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
    if (text.equals(""))
        mTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    else
        mTextView.setText(text);

    mDialog.setCancelable(remove);
    // aiImage.post(new Starter(activityIndicator));
    mDialog.show();
}
```

**popup_example.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@android:id/progress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"></ProgressBar>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Loading Content"
            android:layout_margin="10dip"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Saurabh, I will check that and reply.

Comment: Thanks Saurabh, that worked. Actually I know about this , but I was asking is there any easy way to do this.